# non-numeric argument to binary operator, AR(1) model

Tags: r, for-loop, runtime-error

I have an exercise to do where I have to run the following AR(1) model:

```
xi =c+φxi−1+ηi (i=1,...,T)
```

I know that ni ~ N(0,1) ; x0 ~ N(c/(1-φ),1/(1-φˆ2)); c= 2 ; φ = 0.6
I am trying to do a for loop. My code is the following:

```
n <- rnorm(T, 0, 1)
c <- 2
phi <- 0.6

x_0 <- rnorm(1,c/(1-phi), 1/(1-phi**2))

v <- vector("numeric", 0)

#for (i in 2:T){

  name <- paste("x", i, sep="_")
  v <- c(v,name)
  v[1] <- c + phi*x_0 + n[1]
  v[i] <- c + phi*v[i-1] + n[i]

}
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
Error in phi * v[i - 1] : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I understand what this error is, but I can't find any solutions to solve it. Could someone please enlighten me? How could I assign numeric values to the name vector?

Thank you!

Comment: You're defining `v` as a numeric vector but then adding `name` to it, which is character, so `v` becomes character. That's why you're getting an error about performing operations on a non-numeric value--`v` isn't numeric. If you're trying to associate names with each value of `v`, set `names(v)` equal to the list of names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're defining `v` as a numeric vector, but then `v <- c(v, name)` turns `v` into a character vector since `name` is character. That's what's causing the error.

If I'm not mistaken, your intent is to assign names to the values in a numeric vector. That's fine, you just need a different approach.

```
n <- rnorm(t)
c <- 2
phi <- 0.6

x_0 <- rnorm(1, c/(1-phi), 1/(1-phi^2))

v <- c + phi*x_0 + n[1]

for (i in 2:t) {
    v[i] <- c + phi*v[i-1] + n[i]
}

names(v) <- paste("x", 1:t, sep="_")
```

Vectors in R don't have a static size; they're dynamically resized as needed. So even though we're initializing `v` with a scalar value, it grows to fit each new value in the loop.

The final step is to give `v` a list of names. This can be accomplished using `names(v) <-`. Take a look at `v` now--it has names!

And as an aside, since `T` is a synonym for `TRUE` in R, it's best not to use `T` as a variable name. Thus I've used `t` here instead.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you seem to need the following. It'll produces 11 elements including the initial x value. You may exclude it later.

```
set.seed(1237)
t <- 10
n <- rnorm(t, 0, 1)
c <- 2
phi <- 0.6
x0 <- rnorm(1, c/(1-phi), 1/(1-phi**2))
v <- c(x0, rep(0, t))

for(i in 2:length(v)) {
  v[i] <- c + phi * v[i-1] + n[i-1]
}
v
[1] 4.967833 4.535847 2.748292 2.792992 5.389548 6.173001 4.526824 3.790483 4.307981 5.442913 4.958193
```